# How to resolve a Promise in a JS file which makes a REST call?

Tags: javascript, jquery, ajax, fetch-api

I have a very basic application that is calling a `REST` `API` on page load and trying to display it's results on the page.

**GreetAPIController.java**

```
@RestController
public class GreetAPIController {

    @GetMapping("/api/greet")
    public String greetWorld() {
        System.out.println("into the greeting api controller...");
        return "Hello World !";
    }

}
```

**index.html**

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<head>
    <title>Fetch API Example</title>
    <meta charset="utf-8">
    <script src="https://code.jquery.com/jquery-3.6.3.js"
            integrity="sha256-nQLuAZGRRcILA+6dMBOvcRh5Pe310sBpanc6+QBmyVM=" crossorigin="anonymous"></script>
    <script src="js/main.js"></script>
</head>

<body>
    <h1>Hello ABC !</h1>
    <!-- Populate below h2 from the API response -->
    <h2 id="greetWorld"></h2>
</body>
</html>
```

**main.js**

```
$(document).ready(function(){
    viewIndex();
});

async function viewIndex() {
    const greetResponsePromise = await greetService.greet();
    console.log('greetResponsePromise: ' + greetResponsePromise);

    greetResponsePromise.then(value => {
      console.log(value);
      $('#greetWorld').append(value); //populate the h2 on the page
    }).catch(err => {
      console.log(err);
    });
}

const greetService = {
    greet: async () => {
        return await http.fetch('/api/greet');
    }
};

const http = {
    fetch: async function(url, options = {}) {
        const response = await fetch(url, {
            headers: {
                'Accept': 'application/json',
                'Content-Type': 'application/json'
            },
            ...options,
        });
        return response;
    }
};
```

When I run the application this is the error that I see in the browser console log

**Error:**

```
greetResponsePromise: [object Response] main.js:7:13
Uncaught (in promise) TypeError: greetResponsePromise.then is not a function
    viewIndex http://localhost:8080/js/main.js:9
    async* http://localhost:8080/js/main.js:2
    jQuery 13
```

Comment: How is the actual problem related to `java`?

Comment: Nothing for java but added the tag since the source code uses java for building the API

Comment: `greetResponsePromise` is not actually a promise! The `await` keyword "unwraps" the value the promise resolves to. You rarely if ever want to combine `async/await` with `.then`, and this way certainly doesn't work.

Comment: I would suggest removing the tag and the backend code from the post, it is noise and not relevant for the problem.

Comment: Removed the `java' tag

Comment: Robin - How do I go about solving this issue. Any example you can point to ?

Comment: simply that what you call `greetResponsePromise` is the same as what you are imagining `value` to be inside your `.then`. So simply move that code to after the `await`.

Answer (score 0):

Got it working with Axios.

**index.html**

```
<script src="https://cdn.jsdelivr.net/npm/axios/dist/axios.min.js"></script>
```

**main.js**

```
$(document).ready(function(){
    greetUser();
    greetWorld();
});


const greetUser = () => {
    axios.get('/api/greet/user')
        .then(response => {
            const greetMsg = response.data;
            console.log('greetUserMsg: ' + greetMsg);
            $('#greetUser').append(greetMsg); //populate the h1 on the page
        })
        .catch(error => console.error(error));
}

const greetWorld = () => {
    axios.get('/api/greet/world')
        .then(response => {
            const greetMsg = response.data;
            console.log('greetWorldMsg: ' + greetMsg);
            $('#greetWorld').append(greetMsg); //populate the h2 on the page
        })
        .catch(error => console.error(error));
}
```